# In JQuery, how to ensure a removed class does not stay in the DOM

Tags: jquery

I've simplified my problem hugely here: I can't remember how to solve this bit of it.

In the code below, why does the colour change after I've removed the "colourme" class from the square? How do I ensure "colourme" is no longer applied following the click?

```
<style>
.square{
   height:100px;
   width:100px;
   background:black;
}

.red{
   background:red;  
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="square colourme"></div>

</body>


<script>

$(".colourme").on("mouseenter", function(){
  $(this).addClass("red");
})
$(".colourme").on("mouseleave", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("red");
})  
$(".square").on("click", function(){
   $(this).removeClass("colourme");
})  

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: dont do multiple click fn's on a single element, so 1 large with a lot of conditions. p.s. if u "must" try "stopPropogations"

Answer (score 2):

You should delegate event, e.g:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".colourme", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
})
```

Or just use more specific CSS rule:

```
.colourme.red {
  background: red;
}
```

Now it really depends what is your expected behaviour which is not really clear from your question regarding keeping on red colour or not.

Comment: Thanks - and yes, I'm trying to keep it on red. Any ideas?! What I'm actually trying to do is flip the square over in a CSS3 way, and keep it on one side when flipped, but didn't want to post miles of code on here...

Comment: It does! Sorry - mine didn't and I still can't spot the difference - probably a sign that I should stop working for the day... But thanks!

Comment: Oh - what's the explanation by the way? Why should I have delegated the event?